# Vuetify: justify-position/align-position vs justify="position"/align="position"

Tags: html, css, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

Is there any difference between those 2?
I can find both examples in the docs:

- https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/parallax/ with the usage of `justify-position/align-position` as CSS classes,
- https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/cards with the usage of `justify="position"/align="position"` directly on HTML tags.

Comment: No difference.  [justify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-row/#props-justify) prop on v-row "Applies the justify-content css property" (there is no such prop on v-card)

Comment: @yoduh, I can see `justify="center"` on this example https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/cards/#variants. To me, it looks like minor improvement, to unify it. It looks like `justify="center"` is being used on `v-row`: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/#justify

Comment: The v-card code example doesn't just use v-card, it also has v-row, v-col, v-container, etc.. Notice `justify="center"` is on v-row, _not_ v-card.  Props are component specific, if you want to know every prop available for v-card, check it's [API page](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-card).  Flexbox related components (v-row) have flexbox related props, e.g. `justify`, which makes sense. The helper classes can be used on any element, e.g. native `<div>` elements, for situations where you want to add flex to something that isn't flex by default.

Comment: Clear, thanks for the answer!